# Get maven properties from external configuration file

Tags: maven, properties-file

I have the wildfly pluging with this properties to externally configure the hostname, user, etc.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>${wildfly.hostname}</hostname>
        <port>${wildfly.port}</port>
        <username>${wildfly.username}</username>
        <password>${wildfly.password}</password>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- <phase>package</phase> -->
            <!-- <goals> -->
            <!-- <goal>deploy</goal> -->
            <!-- </goals> -->
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

then I have created a file with the properties (file.properties)

```
wildfly.hostname=127.0.0.1
wildfly.port=19990
wildfly.username=user
wildfly.password=pass
```

And I want that when calling `mvn wildfly:deploy` the variables are taken from the file. I have tried several ways:

1. Using `<properties>` and it works, but it is inside the pom.xml
2. Using `properties-maven-plugin` to load the external file using `<phase>pre-clean</phase>` but it doesn't work.

The issue here is that at the end I would like to create a configuration folder with different profiles, that is, different users, pass, etc.

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Why are you using `<phase>pre-clean</phase>`? Use `<phase>initialize</phase>`

Comment: I have also used it, and it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, you need to invoke `mvn initialize wildfly:deploy`, otherwise, the phase won't be run. Only the execution `wildfly:deploy` would be invoked.

Comment: Thanks that made the trick. It works!! BTW do you know if it would be possible to achieve the same without using `properties-maven-plugin`? I mean using `<filters>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bind the `properties-maven-plugin` to the `pre-clean` phase. It would be more appropriate to bind it to the `initialize` phase. From the [lifecycle reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference):

> `initialize`: initialize build state, e.g. set properties or create directories.

The issue, however, is that this phase will not be run when you directly invoke `mvn wildfly:deploy`. By doing this, you are telling Maven to only run an execution of the `wildfly-maven-plugin`. As such, it won't execute any of the built-in phases of the default or the clean lifecycle.

In your case, you actually need those properties to be setup, so you need the `initialize` phase to run. For that, you can use `mvn initialize wildfly:deploy`. The advantage of using `initialize` here is that the rest of the phases of the default lifecycle won't run so it'll be just as fast as before.

In Maven, `<filters>` have a different purposes: they are used to modify content of resources by replacing placeholders in them with specific values, that can come from a properties file. So `<filters>` aren't for this use-case, and the `properties-maven-plugin` is perfect for it.

Comment: Coudl you please provide an example on how should I configure the stuff for using properties in a persistence.xml? Should I include the filtering? And to run mvn what are the options?

Comment: @jlanza `persistence.xml` is a project resource so you would need filtering for that yes. You can look at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html to see example of filtering.